# Planar TSP: no node insertion?

Tags: algorithms, traveling-salesman, planar-graphs

Since planar TSP with n nodes is NP-hard, we cannot simply find an optimal solution with n-1 nodes and then insert the remaining node at one of the solution's edges to find the optimal solution of the original TSP problem. So, is there a planar graph with an optimal solution, such that when we add a certain extra node, the new graph's optimal solution has *none* of the edges of the previous optimal solution?

Comment: When you say planar TSP, do you mean Euclidean TSP? I.e. a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with Euclidean distances?

Comment: yesm that's what I mean.